# Finding middle element of std::list<string>?

Tags: c++, list, binary-search-tree, stdlist

I am given a list of strings and would like to find the middle element.
I want this middle element because I am constructing a binary search tree from this list, using the middle element as the root node.

How would I go about finding the middle element of standard list so I can recursively call the left and right sides to make the tree? I understand everything about the BST besides this part.

Comment: You would start by writing the best code you know how to write and then seeing if it works.   If it doesn't work, then you would post it here along with a description of what doesn't work for someone to help you with a specific problem.

Comment: You should also check if your list is having an odd number of values... Or else it is not possible to find **a middle element** (It will be two middle elements)

Comment: @Ruks well, depending on what version of c++ you're using, that may be an anti-optimization to do in a separate step, as std::list::size() has not always been required to be O(1).  And if it's not a separate step, then you'll find out whether there's an even/odd number at the exact same time you find the middle element or not...https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size

Comment: The obvious answer is: `auto mid = std::next(l.begin(), l.size() / 2);` (it does pick, of course, a random one out of the two in case `l.size()` is even).

Comment: @ruks that's not my point.

Comment: @xaxxon: that works perfectly, even if `size()` is O(n). The overall effort is O(n) anyway.

Comment: @xaxxon "*then you'll find out whether there's an even/odd number at the exact same time you find the middle element*"... Not in case of dividing two *non-floating-point* numbers...

Comment: @DietmarKühl right, it's just kinda sloppy.   If you're moving two pointers then you can at least have two loads in flight at once while you walk the list

Comment: @xaxxon: if someone wants to implement a tree, `std::list` isn't the way to go. Also, `std::list::size()` is required to be O(1) (if you use an older library update it to conform to be standard conforming).

Comment: @DietmarKühl the question is not marked c++11

Comment: @xaxxon: excellent: the change wasn't done for C++11 (if I recall correctly) and C++ clearly refers to the current standard which is C++17.

Comment: @DietmarKühl the text that pops up when you hover states the *exact opposite*  " Use this tag for questions about code (to be) compiled with a C++ compiler.  Use a version specific tag for questions related to a specific standard revision [C++11], [C++17], etc."

Comment: @xaxxon: sure. The standard isn't a specific version. The tags don't indicate that an outdated C++ version is being used.

Comment: @xaxxon Please referer to tag wiki https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info *"Tag usage: … Unless the question explicitly mentions which version of the C++ standard that is used, it is assumed that the current version is used."*

Answer (score 0):

You could use `size()` and then dividing it by 2 and storing in an integer. Later if you want left or right side you just take that number and add a -1 or a +1